# Fast fuzzy search in C++ container

Tags: c++, containers, fuzzy-search

Suppose a class is defined as follows:

```
class Test
{
public:
    Test(int arg)
    {
        x = arg;
    }

    bool fuzzyEqual(const Test& other) const {
        if (abs(x - other.x) < FUZZY_EQUAL)
            return true;
        else return false;
    }

    int x;

private:
    static const int FUZZY_EQUAL = 5;
};
```

Now suppose we have a `std::vector<Test>` with a lot of elements.

Given a new `Test` object, is linear search the fastest way to find the *first* element in the vector that is "fuzzy" equal (similar) to it?

Furthermore, is there a container that works like `std::map` but that accepts the concept of similarity and not equality?

**As for why I am asking**:
I have several values that represent some other objects (in my case, an integer represents an image), and similar images result in similar values. When inserting the values one at a time in a container, I want to avoid adding a value if a similar one is already present. I do not care that different orders of inserting result in different containers.

Comment: overloading the `==` to be nontransitive is bad practice, please use `bool isSimilar(const Test&)` or something instead.

Comment: @MooingDuck Fixed, thanks!

Comment: I feel there's a perfectly sensible question hidden behind a nonsensical facade. Perhaps if you tell us what you're really trying to do we can give solutions to that.

Comment: Particularly I'm interested in why you want a `std::map`. It sounds like an interval tree or `map` you search for the closest match in might solve your problem instead.

Comment: @Veedrac I have added my specific problem.

Comment: Great. That's much easier. Use a `map` of non-fuzzy values and before insertion just check that the value you're inserting is not `fuzzyEqual` to its `upper_bound` or `lower_bound` in the map.

Answer (score 1):

You could sort the vector and use binary search to find the positions, that have the smallest distance to the point.

For instance `std::lower_bound` gives you the smallest value >= your initial value in `O(log(n))`. And the previous element `--std::lower_bound` is the biggest element < your initial value. If there is a fuzzy value, that is equal, then one of these two found values is the searched one.

Comment: I think you need `std::next(std::lower_bound)` instead, FWIW.